# Flutter-Unity Integration Error(AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError)

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine, widget

'flutter_unity_widget-2022.2.0' is being used to integrate flutter and unity.
In addition to the functions provided by the existing package, custom functions have been created and used.
In the existing version of unity 2020.3.27f1, a function that runs without problems outputs the following error after upgrading to unity 2021.3.19f1. Can I solve the problem?

Error Text : [This is not Working in flutter] :java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Ljava/lang/Object;" field "mUnityPlayer" in class "Lcom/company/projectname/MainActivity;" or its superclasses

Unity AndroidManager.cs code

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
public class AndroidManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static AndroidManager _AndroidManager;

    readonly string PakageName = "com.xraph.plugin.flutter_unity_widget.UnityPlayerUtils";

    private void Awake()
    {
        try
        {
            UnityActivityClass = new AndroidJavaClass(PakageName);
            Debug.Log("[UnityActivityClass]" + UnityActivityClass);
            UnityActivityClass.CallStatic("GetUnityCallback", new AndroidCallbackManager());
            Debug.Log("unity-flutter CallbackManager operation");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("[This is not Working in flutter] :" + e.Message);
        }
    }

    AndroidJavaClass UnityActivityClass;
}
```

Unity AndroidCallbackManager.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using static RoomManager;
using static AndroidManager;
public class AndroidCallbackManager : AndroidJavaProxy
{
    public AndroidCallbackManager() : base("com.xraph.plugin.flutter_unity_widget.UnityCallbackInterface") { }


    public void MyRoomEntrance(string Roomid, string idx, string RoomName, string TargetFurniture)
    {
        //customCode
    }


}
```

add flutter_unity_widget UnityPlayerUtils.kt

```
..//
        var UnityManager: UnityCallbackInterface? = null

    
        fun RoomEntrance(Roomid: String, idx: String,RoomName: String,TargetFurniture: String){
            Log.d("RoomEntrance", "RoomEntrance: ${Roomid}")
            UnityManager?.MyRoomEntrance(Roomid, idx,RoomName,TargetFurniture)
        }



        @JvmStatic
        public fun GetUnityCallback(UnityCallback: UnityCallbackInterface) {
            Log.d("GetUnityCallback", "what is : ${UnityManager}")
            UnityManager = UnityCallback
        }
//..
```

create flutter_unity_widget UnityCallbackInterface.kt

```
package com.xraph.plugin.flutter_unity_widget

public interface UnityCallbackInterface {
    fun MyRoomEntrance(Roomid: String, idx: String, RoomName: String, TargetFurniture: String)
}
```

I tried to solve the problem using ChatGPT, but I couldn't solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this issue as well and have done a lot of digging to determine the cause. I've posted a bug to the FlutterUnityWidget github: https://github.com/juicycleff/flutter-unity-view-widget/issues/836. The proposed workarounds don't really offer a solution to the problem but the problem is at least well described and may offer some insight into fixing the issue.